# Find if a column in dataframe has neither nan nor none

Tags: python, pandas

I have gone through all posts on the website and am not able to find solution to my problem.

I have a dataframe with 15 columns. Some of them come with `None` or `NaN` values. I need help in writing the if-else condition.

If the column in the dataframe is not null and nan, I need to format the datetime column. Current Code is as below

```
for index, row in df_with_job_name.iterrows():
    start_time=df_with_job_name.loc[index,'startTime']
    if not df_with_job_name.isna(df_with_job_name.loc[index,'startTime']) :
        start_time_formatted =
            datetime(*map(int, re.split('[^\d]', start_time)[:-1]))
```

The error that I am getting is

```
if not df_with_job_name.isna(df_with_job_name.loc[index,'startTime']) :
TypeError: isna() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Thanks I tried using null_map_df = df_with_job_name.isna(). It worked for a small number of test records. But while i was iterating over 700 items in this dataframe it returned false for one of the nan values

Answer (score 0):

`isna` takes your entire data frame as the instance argument (that's `self`, if you're already familiar with classes) and returns a data frame of Boolean values, `True` where that value is invalid.  You tried to specify the individual value you're checking as a second input argument.  `isna` doesn't work that way; it takes empty parentheses in the call.

You have a couple of options.  One is to follow the individual checking tactics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754891/python-nan-value-in-pandas-for-a-single-value-only).  The other is to make the map of the entire data frame and use that:

```
null_map_df = df_with_job_name.isna()

for index, row in df_with_job_name.iterrows() :
    if not null_map_df.loc[index,row]) :
        start_time=df_with_job_name.loc[index,'startTime']
        start_time_formatted =
            datetime(*map(int, re.split('[^\d]', start_time)[:-1]))
```

Please check my use of row & column indices; the `index, row` handling doesn't look right.  Also, you *should* be able to apply an `any` operation to the entire row at once.

Answer (score 0):

A direct way to take care of missing/invalid values is probably:

```
def is_valid(val):
    if val is None:
       return False
    try:
       return not math.isnan(val)
    except TypeError:
       return True
```

and of course you'll have to import `math`.

Also it seems `isna` is not invoked with any argument and returns a dataframe of boolean values (see [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html)). You can iterate thru both dataframes to determine if the value is valid.